# R, scale_fill_stepsn() error in breaks and colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, break, colorbar

I am using `scale_fill_stepsn()` because I want a tailored colorbar in my `geom_tile()` plot.

Therefore, I choose 6 colors and 5 breaks as follows:

```
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", colors=c("#9ecae1",  # dark blue
                                        "#c6dbef",  # medium blue
                                        "#eff3ff",  # light blue
                                         
                                        "#fee5d9",  # dark red
                                        "#fcbba1",  # medium red
                                        "#fc9272"), # light red
                    breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50))
```

The color palette has 3 tones of blue and 3 of red, the values plotted with `geom_tile()` are both negative and positive, and hence the `breaks()`.

Therefore, I am expecting that `scale_fill_stepsn()` will put the colors as follows:

```
#9ecae1 -25 #c6dbef -10 #eff3ff 0 #fee5d9 10 #fcbba1 50 #fc9272
```

But instead I get the following:

[image: figure]

Any idea what is happing here?

#################
UPDATE

here [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad7g65vxtnzt4v1/test.rds?dl=0):

and sample script:

```
plot_1 = ggplot() +
  
  geom_tile(data=test, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = median)) +
  
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", colors=c("#9ecae1",
                                        "#c6dbef",
                                        "#eff3ff",
                                        "#fee5d9",
                                        "#fcbba1",
                                        "#fc9272"),
                    breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit3**

You should add `limits` to let it know where the breaks should. If you just one value higher and lower to the breaks it knows how to rescale the values like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_1 = ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=test, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = median)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", 
                    colors =c("#2171b5", "#6baed6", "#bdd7e7", "#fcae91", "#fb6a4a", "#cb181d"),
                    breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50),
                    limits = c(-26, 51),
                    values = scales::rescale(c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50))) 
plot_1
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit2**

Your breaks need to be set at your minimum and maximum values. You can create a `seq` of values with `min` and `max`. The values are used to map these values between 0 and 1. You need 1 more breaks because of the length of your palette, and that's why you get a grey color every time. You can use the following code:

```
plot_1 = ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=test, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = median)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", 
                    colors =c("#2171b5", "#6baed6", "#bdd7e7", "#fcae91", "#fb6a4a", "#cb181d"),
                    breaks = seq(min(test$median), max(test$median), length = 7),
                    values = scales::rescale(seq(min(test$median), max(test$median), length = 6))) 
plot_1
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit1**

You should mention the `breaks` in your `values` argument too with a `rescale` range between 0 and 1, because your colors are not evenly positioned. Here you can see what the documenation says about the argument values:

> if colours should not be evenly positioned along the gradient this
> vector gives the position (between 0 and 1) for each colour in the
> colours vector. See rescale() for a convenience function to map an
> arbitrary range to between 0 and 1.

You could use `rescale` from `scales` package for that. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_1 = ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=test, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = median)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", 
                    colors =c("#9ecae1", "#c6dbef", "#eff3ff", "#fee5d9", "#fcbba1", "#fc9272"),,
                    breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50),
                    values = scales::rescale(c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50))) 
plot_1
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, now the colors are shown right!

Different colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_1 = ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=test, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = median)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", 
                    colors =c("#2171b5", "#6baed6", "#bdd7e7", "#fcae91", "#fb6a4a", "#cb181d"),
                    breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50),
                    values = scales::rescale(c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 25, 50))) 
plot_1
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Old answer**

It seems that the hex code colors you use, are different than you think. You could use the package `plotrix` to check the color names of the hex codes. You can see it suggests something different below here:

```r
library(ggplot2)
plot_1 = ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=test, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = median)) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "", 
                    colors = c("lightskyblue2", "lightsteelblue2", "aliceblue", "antiquewhite", "burlywood2", "salmon1"),
                    breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50)) 
plot_1
```

[image]

```r
library(plotrix)
sapply(c("#9ecae1", "#c6dbef", "#eff3ff", "#fee5d9", "#fcbba1", "#fc9272"), color.id)
#>           #9ecae1           #c6dbef           #eff3ff           #fee5d9 
#>   "lightskyblue2" "lightsteelblue2"       "aliceblue"    "antiquewhite" 
#>           #fcbba1           #fc9272 
#>      "burlywood2"         "salmon1"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: nope, sorry. I tried with: colors=c("blue",
                                        "dodgerblue",
                                        "lightskyblue",
                                        
                                         "salmon",
                                         "tomato",
                                         "red") and it is still wrong.

Comment: @aaaaa, I updated my answer! You should mention the breaks in the values argument with a range between 0 and 1. For that, you can use `rescale` from `scales` package. As you cans see the colors are right now!

Comment: Wow thank you! I will soon try it and if it works choose yours as best answer

Comment: hi, I don't think it works 100%. can you try the following: colors =c("#2171b5", "#6baed6", "#bdd7e7", "#fcae91", "#fb6a4a", "#cb181d"). why the 4th color appears grey instead of: https://www.colorhexa.com/fcae91 ? is this a bug of ggplot?

Comment: Hi @aaaaa, you should have the same number of colors and breaks in `values`. See updated answer!

Comment: yes of course. the color between 0 and 10 is still not correct though. :(

Comment: @aaaaa, I added a second edit! You should use breaks between the min and max of your values with an extra break. That's why you every time get a grey color.

Comment: wrong. in your last update I have equal breaks. whereas I need the following uneven breaks: breaks = c(-25, -10, 0, 10, 50))

Comment: @aaaaa, Now it should work ;). You should add `limits` to let it know where to stop the breaks to it can apply the colors like above.

Comment: now it looks correct. I will soon test it 