# ggplot2 function scale_fill_stepsn colors do not match

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some codes that want to show a map with unequal color breaks and assign each category with a specific color. I used the `scale_fill_stepsn` function.

Here are my codes:

```
ggplot(data = rate) + 
    geom_sf(aes(fill = rate))+theme_bw()+
      scale_fill_stepsn(name = "Test Rate \n (n/1000)", 
                    colors =c("#999999","#6666FF", "#FFFF66","#FF6633"),
                    breaks = c(0,1, 10, 100),
                    labels=scales::label_number(accuracy=1),
                    show.limits = TRUE) +
    annotation_north_arrow(location = "tl", which_north = "true", 
        pad_x = unit(0.1, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.05, "in"),
        height = unit(1, "cm"),
        width = unit(1, "cm"),
        style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering)+
    annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.2)
```

[image: The Figure]

The exact colours I put in the function shows below, which do not match the colour in the result figure.

```
scales::show_col(c("#999999","#6666FF", "#FFFF66","#FF6633"))
```

[image]

[data](https://github.com/zhenchun/data)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Where do these annotation functions come from? If they're not needed for the specific question, you could remove those parts of the code so we don't have to install extra packages. You're setting up a gradient, but of colors that seemingly won't blend together nicely. An orange to blue gradient is going to look pretty muddy—seems like that's what you got as output

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224130/r-scale-fill-stepsn-error-in-breaks-and-colors

Comment: I have uploaded the data here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add `trans = scales::log10_trans(),` to the `scale_fill_stepsn` I get better results for this reproducible example, because my breaks are log distributed, so my gradient should be too. Otherwise the gradient will apply linearly along 0:107, and most values will be in muddled gray land.

```
ggplot(data.frame(val = c(0, 1, 10, 100, 107), x = 1:5),
       aes(x, 0, fill = val)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_stepsn(name = "Test Rate \n (n/1000)", 
                    colors =c("#999999","#6666FF", "#FFFF66","#FF6633"),
                    breaks = c(0,1, 10, 100), 
                    trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(), #  ADDED THIS LINE
                    labels=scales::label_number(accuracy=1),
                    show.limits = TRUE)
```

With

[image]

Without

[image]